# How to improve boot performance of PCs with Windows OS

Tags: windows, performance, boot

Years ago I was using a Microsoft program called BootVis.exe to optimize and improve boot performance of my PCs. It was successful in decreasing the opening time of Windows XP. Now I have machines with Windows XP and Windows 7. Is BootVis still being used? What free tool should I use to improve the boot performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think http://www.soluto.com/ will help you.

Comment: sadly soluto  domain seems parked. and most of the companies block parked domains. Does not seem safe

Comment: Soluto is fine.  I've been using it for about 18 months without a hassle, and no security issues.  Note: if you uninstall Soluto, you lose all the performance tweaks you made with Soluto.

Answer (score 0):

BootVis is apparently no longer available from Microsoft, likely because it didn't work that well, and considering the number of people that complained that a free software did not speed up their computer (even though it said it might not...) Anyways, it is still available from other sources, like MajorGeeks.com and Softpedia (though I tend to shy away from such sites). It, however, does not appear to be designed to work with Windows 7. If you really care about the few tenths of a second, try running it in a VM, just to make sure it doesn't make the boot process slower.